# some important density result

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

I was told (quite often) that  $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$ for all $p\in[1,\infty)$.

And I did realise there are some related results posted here. 
But I would like a standard proof.
I have found p.7 in
[enter link description here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m526/Lecture3.pdf)

as a proof for the claim ($\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$). However I would like the proof of a result goes before that, which is the one I asked for.

Hope anyone could provide a proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: $C_0$ is dense in $L^p$. This follows from Lusin's theorem.

Step 2: $C^\infty_0$ is dense in $C_0$. This is the usual argument of convolution with a mollifier.

Step 3: If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C_0$ then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$. So the $L^p$-closure of $C^\infty_0$ contains $C_0$, and the $L^p$-closure of $C_0$ is $L^p$. Thus $\overline{\overline{C^\infty_0}}=L^p$, where we take the closure in $L^p$. But $\overline{\overline{C^\infty_0}}=\overline{C^\infty_0}$, so the result follows.

I think, with some care, one can shorten this proof and instead show directly that one can can convolve an $L^p$ function with a mollifier to get a $C^\infty_0$ approximation of the $L^p$ function. But I think this proof is somewhat more technical.

Comment: Thanks Ian. But I have trouble understanding your step 3. What is the reference for your proof?

Comment: @math101 Any measure theoretical real analysis textbook will contain a proof of this, I think. All the ones I have seen have been in the above spirit.